# Java - How can i increase the font of the folder names in JFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing, font-size, jfilechooser

When running my Java program on a high resolution 4k screen the font of the folder names in the JFileChooser appear tiny, as it appear here:

[image]

I am trying to find a way to increase the folder/file name font size only in the JFileChooser. The current idea i have is to create a custom JFileChooser, loop on its elements and try to increase the font of the folder names. I thought i'd increase the font of the FilePane, but it doesn't work. Nothing happens. Here is my code:

```
public class JFileChooserCustom extends JFileChooser {
    public JFileChooserCustom() {
        setFileChooserFont( this.getComponents() );
    }

    public void setFileChooserFont( Component[] comp ) {
        for( int x = 0; x < comp.length; x++ ) {
          // System.out.println( comp[x].toString() );  // Trying to know the type of each element in the JFileChooser.
          if(comp[x] instanceof Container) setFileChooserFont(((Container)comp[x]).getComponents());

          try{
              if(comp[x] instanceof FilePane) comp[x].setFont( comp[x].getFont().deriveFont( comp[x].getFont().getSize() * 2f ) );
          }
          catch(Exception e){}//do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone could assist me with this.

Comment: See also the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784) - in case you decide to give up on `JFileChooser` and replace it.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson ... Thanks, but it seems very advanced. I don't need such sophisticated chooser :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't work with FilePane, use JList and JTable instead (these components are used by FilePane to present file list).

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 * <code>IncreaseFileChooserFont</code>.
 */
public class IncreaseFileChooserFont {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                setFileChooserFont(chooser.getComponents());
                chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void setFileChooserFont(Component[] comp) {
        for (int x = 0; x < comp.length; x++) {
            // System.out.println( comp[x].toString() ); // Trying to know the type of each element in the JFileChooser.
            if (comp[x] instanceof Container)
                setFileChooserFont(((Container) comp[x]).getComponents());

            try {
                if (comp[x] instanceof JList || comp[x] instanceof JTable)
                    comp[x].setFont(comp[x].getFont().deriveFont(comp[x].getFont().getSize() * 2f));
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } // do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by individually setting the font of every component of JFilechooser.

```
// Inside method where you are preparing your JFilechooser:  
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(".");  
setFileChooserFont(fc.getComponents());  

public void setFileChooserFont(Component[] comp)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < comp.length; x++)
    {
      if(comp[x] instanceof Container) setFileChooserFont(((Container)comp[x]).getComponents());
      try{comp[x].setFont(font);}
      catch(Exception e){}//do nothing
    }
}
```

Hope this will help. :-)